# Casperjs doesn't open some other websites

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using Casperjs for downloading Websites. Until now every website I used with casperjs works fine. Now I want to add another website.

```
casper.start('http://www.example.de', function() {
      var page = this.getHTML();
      this.echo(page);
});
```

If I run this code with casperjs on my Desktop (Windows) it works. But If I run this same code on a server (centos) it shows me this:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Why is it empty? I even tried to execute the js-file like this:

casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=no example.js

But it still shows me: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

There is only problem with the one Website-Url. It isn't even a https-Website. Simple http and html Website.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Shall I update casperjs and phantomjs? It is weird because it works on my local desktop but not on a V-Server. :(

Comment: After debugging it shows me this:                                                                                           [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 3 ( "Host www.example.de not found" ) URL: "http://www.example.de/"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The Problem was with the DNS. (/etc/resolv.conf)